# NGINX: Serve /images/ folder statically

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've already tried so much stuff in order to do this, also, by putting a php file inside /images/test.php to test if it will be downloaded or executed, and it always gets executed.

Also, I have lots of seo rewrites, so I don't really know what is happening.

This is what I am currently trying (and I already red lots of docs about it):

Server Config:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    #proxy_cache off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_header_timeout 10m;
    client_body_timeout 10m;
    send_timeout 10m;

    connection_pool_size 256;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 2k;
    request_pool_size 4k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain;

    output_buffers 1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 75 20;

    ignore_invalid_headers on;

    index index.php;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 8k;
    proxy_buffers 2048 8k;

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1;
        server_name <<my_domain>>;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_<<my_domain>> main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_<<my_domain>> info;

        root <<doc_root>>;

        error_page 403 /errors.php?type=403;
        error_page 404 /errors.php?type=404;

        location ~* /images  {
            root    <<doc_root>>;
            #expires 30d;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            #internal;
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires off;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
        }

        #For virtual folders which are links seo-friendly and language
                location ~ (*UTF8)^.*$ {
                        include "rewrites.conf";
                }

    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:443;
        server_name <<my_domain>>;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:RC4-SHA;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_ssl_<<my_domain>> main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_ssl_<<my_domain>> info;

        root <<doc_root>>;
        error_page 403 /errors.php?type=403;
        error_page 404 /errors.php?type=404;

        <<the_same_locations_than_www_server_before>>
    }
}
```

So, can I serve all content inside `/images/` statically without passing through php? In this testcase, the file `/images/test.php` should be downloaded rather than showing `phpinfo();`

Comment: After rebooting everything, it seems to work, but, any advise on this prior to mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ~* matches but continues searching for other regex matches I think what you want is:

```
    location ^~ /images/  {
        #This should match /images/ and stop checking.
        root    <<doc_root>>;
        #expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #internal;
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
    }
```

Comment: And what about putting more than one folder in the same location rule? Something like ^~ /(images|js|css)/ do not work _:(

Comment: This took some digging but it looks like you can't use a regex with ^~ because it stops as soon as it matches.  I'm not explaining it well but the short answer is you can't.  See configuration D [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

Comment: Thanks :) Sometimes nginx configuration is a little tricky. Anyway I added the rest of static folders as intependent locations using the syntax you provided

Answer (score 0):

Based on your location blocks, files ending with '.php' will only be passed through PHP. So if you have an actual file in the '/images' directory, it should serve it as a static file, or otherwise return a 404 error. If the file ends with '.php' and is in the '/images' directory, it will run through both location blocks in order.

Should it do otherwise?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to serve it statically, regardless of content, if it is inside /images/ folder.